# perform a query with mysql function like now() in bookshelf.js

Tags: mysql, bookshelf.js, knex.js

in Knex.js/bookshelf.js how do i do the following

```
select * from `events` where end_time >= now()
```

Passing now in a where() causes it to be taken as a parameter and not as a function

```
 qb.andWhere("end_time", ">=", "now()");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure in bookshelf, but taken it uses Knex directly, I'd say you should try:

```
qb.andWhere("end_time", ">=", knex.fn.now());
```

Comment: i went with a raw query whereRaw.(see my answer) what's the diff b/w the two

Comment: I suppose that sending raw doesn't take into account the database you are connecting to (I'm not sure Knex.fn.now() does, but it *should*)

Comment: one minor(or should i say negligible) irritant  to your solution is having to import knex

Comment: Since bookshelf is using knex already, that should be no issue

Comment: i meant the require statement ;)

Answer (score 1):

The key is to use a raw query. Knex comes with with a option of using raw query. This will stop now() from becoming a  parameter(i.e ?) to the query

```
MyModel.forge()
     .query(function(qb) {
        qb.whereRaw("end_time >= now()")
     })
```

Comment: The problem with the raw approach is that you depend on your database provider to have that name function that does what you want. In practice most DB providers (that provide SQL) have a `NOW()` function these days, but it wasn't like that before (the common is `GETDATE()`). Using `knex.fn.now()` should allow it to be provider-dependant (I'm not actually sure if the implementation ***is***, but it ***could*** be, while sending raw queries couldn't)

Comment: an lazy question. what does knex.fn.now() do

Comment: Probably its current implementation just converts to a raw `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` or simply a `NOW` as you are doing here. But that's an implementation detail

Comment: you mean it happens in JS(i.e it's a js code that returns the current timestamp) not db level

Comment: I don't understand. `knex.fn.now()` is a javascript function, that *probably* returns a raw command of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` or `NOW` which gets appended to the query your are constructing. Of course the actual datetime retrieval happens on the database provider, not on javascript.

Comment: It seems it does `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` actually: https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/blob/master/src/functionhelper.js . But again, that's an implementation detail that might change (if, for example, more db providers are supported in the future). That's why you should be using this function instead of directly constructing the raw query